# Snap to Roads using Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I'm currently looking for the Mapbox Snap to Roads API the same as [Google map Snap to Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_374137922075-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20%7E%20Routes%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Snap%20to%20Roads-KWID_43700046143621441-aud-596763661393:kwd-424177854692-userloc_1009829&utm_term=KW_%2Bsnap%20%2Bto%20%2Broad-ST_%2Bsnap%20%2Bto%20%2Broad&gclid=Cj0KCQjwl4v4BRDaARIsAFjATPnaI-oUymdytaS_yEIsoZkEq4PCAlALg3AZDIFlcJ_L62HqPp3tJ5UaAsQDEALw_wcB). Is there any Mapbox APIs the same as Google map Snap to Roads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [Map Matching API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#map-matching).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Might be a better question for gis.stackexchange.com